# How do I properly install and run Thin?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, webserver, thin

How does one install and run Thin? According to the [official page](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), I can start it with `bundle exec thin start`, but no dice. Instead I get `Could not locate Gemfile`. If I restart Terminal and run `gem install thin` again, it seems to install it again as if it weren't properly installed the first time.

[image: Sceeenshot of Terminal output]

Comment: Don't use an image to show us errors or code. We can't copy/paste the content to search and help you, and, when that link breaks your question won't make any sense.

Comment: @theTinMan The error `Could not locate Gemfile` is typed out in the plain text part of my question.

Comment: The point is, don't use images except when absolutely necessary, for the reasons I said. Images can't be indexed by search engines, which also limits their usefulness to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Add the output of `rvm info` to your question by editing your question and copying/pasting the output.

Answer (score 0):

The guide assumes you're using it in a Ruby project. Using `bundle ...` requires there to be a Gemfile in the current directory. It'll work if you `cd` to a Ruby project and add `gem thin` to your Gemfile.

Here's some info on Gemfiles: http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html